# Is there a WYSIWYG editor for biblatex styles?

Tags: biblatex, tools, wysiwyg

Does anyone know if a WYSIWYG editor for `biblatex` exists, where I simply can enter some kind of template (e.g. regular expression or whatever) and the needed commands to produce this style would be generated.

Especially for the style of entries in the reference list. Considering different orders of e.g. author, journal, year ... brackets or not, or colon, semicolon or just a dot and so on.

From what I saw on the net, LyX seems to be not compatible with `biblatex`.

I think this would be a helpful tool – not only for `biblatex` newbies.

### Remark

This question seeks for:

- Generators of BibLaTeX *styles*, not of BibLaTeX *contents*.
- Hence only a tool whose output is a set of BibLaTeX commands to be put in a document preamble is what the answers should be about.
- Examples of what are *not* the right tools (making **not valid answers**):

  - JabRef, BibDesk, ... (manages bibliography entries, not BibLaTeX styles)
  - `makebst`, `custom-bib`, ... (good try, but it is for BibTeX, not BibLaTeX)

Comment: `LyX` is an editor and has nothing to do with `biblatex`. You have to configure `LyX` how it should run the bibliography commands.

Comment: I have a project in mind, but it's still a work in progress. `:(`

Comment: you can also use "bakoma Tex"

Comment: @PauloCereda Will it be WYSIWYG? I thought you were working on something analogous to makebst.

Comment: @Audrey: I thought of providing both. `:)` The default would be a CLI (command-line interface), and with a special `--gui` flag which would trigger a UI interaction. My plan is to share these ideas with PLK, Joseph and specially you. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda This would be very nice, feel free to ask for any help you need.

Comment: @jeecabz, How can BaKoMa TeX exactly help with bibliography (specifically `biblatex`) templates?

Comment: @VicentGiner-Bosch, my apology, but I did not much explore on this application. I think you can have it "INSERT" Menu.

Comment: A good inspiration can (perhaps) be found in the visual CSL editor: http://csleditor.quist.de/csleditor/show/1/example-citation-style

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Comment: JabRef has an ability to create new styles. Options -> Preferences -> Entry Preview. Maybe this helps

Comment: @susis, does it need to be `biblatex`? If you go for a fully custom style, might `librarian` be an option? I know it is not WYSIWYG, but it might help you bypass some problems altogether. I would say it is definitely worth a look at, if you have not seen it before. http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/generic/librarian/doc/generic/librarian/

Comment: @jmc For this question, yes ;-) But it's indeed an interesting tip, I will have a closer look on.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in Windows or Mac?

Comment: @wierts Personally, I only use Linux (Ubuntu) and if I forced to use Windows I have an old Win98. I never use/used Mac. But to answer the question and the wide community of people it may concern, we should be independent of an OS.

Comment: @PauloCereda More then a year is over, do you have any news for us about your project?

Comment: @PauloCereda Well, now it's been more than two years, do you have any news for us about your project?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a better solution would be an editor that would let you drag and drop example field values from an (extensible) list of fieldnames into a template for each type of document (book, article, report, incollection, etc), in the order you want them to appear. Add any punctuation, and then make the relevant bits italic or bold etc, and use that as the template to generate the biblatex style.

This would make a nice little web/css/xml/js project, tied to a server-side TeX installation which would display the worked examples as they are composed.

AFAIK, the strict answer to the OP's question is "No".

Comment: Thay's why there are no answers :)

Comment: Thanks for the inspired conversations, I might have to wait for a bit as it seems