# natbib: Split Bibliography Into Sections By Entrytype (without using multibib)

Tags: bibtex, lyx, natbib, subdividing

### What's wrong with `multibib`?

`multibib` lets me split up my bibliography. But I have to specify manually (by `\citeabc` or `\citedef`), which bibliography entry belongs to which section. Also, it's not (really) compatible with `LyX`.

### What do I want?

I want to create a `book` including `natbib`'s `author-date` cites and bibliography using `LyX`.

My `\bibliography` should be splitted into 2 parts:

- `@ELECTRONIC` (**Electronical resources**)
- non-`@ELECTRONIC` (**Books, jornals etc.**)

I don't want to do this by hand because it's error-prone on big bibliographies and just redundant.

### My Question:

What's the best way to **automatically split up a `natbib` bibliography** into an `@ELECTRONIC` and a non-`@ELECTRONIC` section (**by the entrytype** of the `.bib` file)?

Thanks for your ideas, for your answers. - If my question isn't clear this way, please write a comment to inform me about that.

### An Example:

```
% file.bib

@ELECTRONIC{Lundmaier,
  %...
}

@ARTICLE{Lundstein,
  %...
}

@BOOK{Lundberg,
  %...
}


% file.tex

\citep{Lundberg, Lundstein, Lundmaier}
\bibliography{file}
```

should result in:

```
== Bibliography ==
= Books and Jornals =
Lundberg, Ulla-Lena ...
Lundstein, Hannah ...

= Electronical Resources =
Lundmaier, Tina ...
```

Comment: have you already considered switching to ``biblatex``? It should provide all the features of ``natbib`` as well as a mechanism where you can put bibliography entries to different bibliographies depending on various criteria (also entry type if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (my first upvote ever ;-) ). - I don't know much about `biblatex`, so I'll try to get some informations about `biblatex` and comment again later on.

Comment: I created my own `.bst` using `custom-bib`'s `makebst` and I really need *that* style. - Do you know: Is there any way to port/convert/use `.bst`s for `biblatex`? (Or at least: Is there a nice toolkit for style creation like `makebst` for `biblatex`?)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there isn't any such tool yet. Compare [Is there a WYSIWYG editor for biblatex styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67248/18674)

Comment: @BenediktBauer Thanks, I'm going to take a look at that...

Comment: @BenediktBauer It seems that this thread didn't get to a solution. There's only a reference to a tool, which is cool, but it doesn't have a `biblatex` style export function. So I'm still searching for a good tool...

Comment: @BenediktBauer I switched to `biblatex` successfully with my own style defined using `\renewcommand*`s in the preamble. - So I'm ready for your `biblatex` sudivision solution now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution based on the `biblatex` package looks as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}{minimal.bib}
@electronic{electronic1,
author = {A. Author},
title = {Funny website},
urldate = {2013-01-09},
url = {http://www.example.org},
},
@book{book1,
author = {B. Bthor},
title = {A Book of whatever},
date = {2012},
},
@article{article1,
author = {C. Cthor and D. Dthor},
title = {Writing interesting articles},
journaltitle = {The Journal of References},
date = {2010-12-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,                    % natbib compatibility mode
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{minimal.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading                    % print heading for all bibliographies
\printbibliography[
    nottype = online,               % Put here verything that is NOT of the type "online".
                                    % The "electronic" type is just an alias to "online" 
    title={Books and Journals},     % title of the subbibliography
    heading=subbibliography         % make bibliography go one sectioning level lower
    ]
\printbibliography[
    type=online,                    % Put only references of the type "online" here.
    title={Electronic Ressources},
    heading=subbibliography
    ]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As I have never used `LyX` I cannot tell how to integrate this into the `LyX` workflow. But as you told that you managed to create a suitable `biblatex` style I guess that you already managed to get `biblatex` working in `LyX`.