# How can I divide thebibliography into sections?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using `thebibliography` to manually create my bibliography. However, I would like to divide it into two sections: academics and practitioners. 
Here is a sample of my bibliography:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem {} Afuah, A. N. and Tucci, C. (2000). \textit{‘Internet business models and strategies: text and cases’}, 1st edition, New York, McGraw-Hill Education.

\bibitem {} Alt, R. and Zimmermann, H.D. (2001). ‘Preface: introduction to special section– business models’, \textit{EM - Electronic Markets}, 11(1): pp. 3-9.
```

I would like to insert a title, after 'Bibliography', which is generated automatically, saying "Academics". If I write anything which is not contained in the \bibitem environment I get an error. However, for the second section, ('Practitioners') which comes after some 30 items, I can insert text manually outside the \bibitem environment, without getting an error. Just like so:

```
\bibitem {} Wilson, H.J. et al. (2016). ‘Companies are re-imagining business processes with algorithms’, \textit{Harvard Business Review}, (February 2016).

%(end of academics section, beginning of practitioners section) 

\begin{huge}
Practitioners
\end{huge}

\medskip

\bibitem {} Harrington, L. (2016). \textit{‘The predictive enterprise: where data science meets supply chain’}, DHL Supply chain. \url{< http://supplychain.dhl.com/LP=704?nu_ref=Vanity-URL>}
```

How can I obtain the same thing but at the beginning of the paragraph? It seems like I can write regular text in the middle of the bibliography but not immediately at the beginning.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Could you consider using `biblatex`?  It has dedicated tools.

Comment: Thank you Kurt for your answer. However, since I have already filled my dissertation with manually entered citations, and since I already have the piece of code necessary for the bibliography, I was wondering if if it wasn't too late to use biblatex or similar, given that I have already done the job. Do you suggest I start using it anyway? Is it going to be a long job, converting the whole bibliography to another format?

Comment: This depends on the number of references, but anyway a bibliography manager like `JabRef` can help avoiding syntax errors. If you post some items from your bibliography, we can show how they should be transformed.

Comment: Thank you Bernard (sorry for calling you Kurt before). I do have 42 references to insert + a webography which is in the making. Here are some examples:  (book)  Afuah, A. N. and Tucci, C. (2000). ‘Internet business models and strategies: text and cases’, 1st edition, New York, McGraw-Hill Education.  (article)  Alt, R. and Zimmermann, H.D. (2001). ‘Preface: introduction to special section– business models’, EM - Electronic Markets, 11(1): pp. 3-9.  (reference with url)  Skok, M. J. (2014). Harvard innovation lab presents ‘Startup secrets’. <http://www.startupsecrets.com >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LaTeX, most people use a bibliography package, mainly `natbib` or `biblatex`. You can use one of them to solve your problem.

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) is a good way to get started.
After getting familiar with that I think the post [natbib: Split Bibliography Into Sections By Entrytype (without using multibib)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89938/natbib-split-bibliography-into-sections-by-entrytype-without-using-multibib) may be the final answer to your question.

What follows is the code that [Benedikt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18674/benedikt-bauer) wrote in the last post mentioned above:

```
\begin{filecontents}{minimal.bib}
@electronic{electronic1,
author = {A. Author},
title = {Funny website},
urldate = {2013-01-09},
url = {http://www.example.org},
},
@book{book1,
author = {B. Bthor},
title = {A Book of whatever},
date = {2012},
},
@article{article1,
author = {C. Cthor and D. Dthor},
title = {Writing interesting articles},
journaltitle = {The Journal of References},
date = {2010-12-01},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
    natbib=true,                    % natbib compatibility mode
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{minimal.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading                    % print heading for all bibliographies
\printbibliography[
    nottype = online,               % Put here verything that is NOT of the type "online".
                                    % The "electronic" type is just an alias to "online" 
    title={Books and Journals},     % title of the subbibliography
    heading=subbibliography         % make bibliography go one sectioning level lower
    ]
\printbibliography[
    type=online,                    % Put only references of the type "online" here.
    title={Electronic Ressources},
    heading=subbibliography
    ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Evariste for your answer. However, since I have already filled my dissertation with manually entered citations, and since I already have the piece of code necessary for the bibliography, I was wondering if if it wasn't too late to use `biblatex` or similar, given that I have already done the job. Do you suggest I start using it anyway? Is it going to be a long job, converting the whole bibliography to another format?

Comment: At least with a text editor like Sublime it shouldn't take so long to copy and paste your references to a .bib file (It's pretty much that: copy-paste). How familiar are you with .bib files?
Furthermore, I don't think inserting a title in the middle of the bibliography without using one of those packages is easier than converting the bibliography to a new format.

Comment: And welcome to TeX SX, I hope you have pleasant journey here!

Comment: Thank you Evariste! Well, how familiar am I...not at all I'm afraid! But this forum is so full of important information that I think I can have it sorted out quickly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following line at the place you want in your thebibliography environment:

\item[]{\emph{Academics}}