# BibLaTeX, how to customize authortitle style?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle

really really new to LaTeX, I must admit.

I was wondering if is it possible to customize a biblatex style since I looked and looked but none matches the one required by my university.

Briefly (an @article here as an example)

**this is what I get with authortitle**: Smith, J. “Article Title”. In:*Journal Name*(1999), pp. 1-10

**this is what I need**: J. Smith, *Article Title* in *Journal Name*, 1999, pp. 1-10

To sum up the differences: **No** quotation marks, **no** parentheses, **no** colon and possibly inverted order in the name.

thanks everybody in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! This is possible, yes, but (in my admittedly limited) experience often difficult. My suggestion would be to find a style that closely matches what your university requires, and then inquire whether using that one would be acceptable. In my experience, many professors don't mind. Generally, also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67248/158639 , BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One example of one particular `@article` entry is by far not enough to implement a complete bibliography style with `biblatex`, but the following can be a start.

The code is based on `ext-authortitle` from my `biblatex-ext` bundle (because that makes a few modifications easier). Most commands below should have fairly self-explanatory names (you can also look up most things in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) or the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf)), but I'll be happy to answer any questions in the comments.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authortitle,
  giveninits,
  uniquename=init
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \bibstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments in Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, 1998, pp. 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and precious help!! I will study how to use this  fantastic extension bundle of yours so, hopefully, I won't bother anymore. 

I'm sorry for my example being poor, I can provide further examples if it is helpful  in any way!